# Programmatically add views in android

Tags: android

I have to add two relative layouts next to each other horizontally in android.I know i have to use addRule concept.But i havent got a proper link to achieve this.Can someone provide me some good tutorials on addRule in  android and also solution for this problem.Thanx![As can be seen the two relative layouts should come within one parentlayout.
Following is my code:

```
       //Layout on which my parentrelativelayout should be added 
        LinearaLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewbyId(R.id.ll);

        RelativeLayout parentrelativelayout=new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        parentrelativelayout.setId(1);
        parentrelativelayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        parentrelativelayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        RelativeLayout rl_relativelayout1 = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        rl_relativelayout1.setId(2);
        rl_relativelayout1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(800,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rl_relativelayout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.voucher_row);

        RelativeLayout rl_relativelayout2=new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        rl_relativelayout2.setId(3);
        rl_relativelayout2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grab_voucher);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

I need to achieve this PROGRAMMATICALLY in android. ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DZzi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is achievable. Check these out.

1. http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html
2. http://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/
3. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/

Another possibility is to draw the Layout on xml but hide it using visibility attribute. Then if condition is met then show it.